# jq doesn't work with keys which contains dash in it from a variable

Tags: jq

If you'd like jq to escape dashes, you need to put your key between square brackets like this;

`jq '.["key-key"]'`

and apart from that, if you'd like to include a variable in jq, you need to use double quotes instead of single quotes;

`jq "."${var[i+1]}""`

but my variable contains dash in it and in this case, I've tried to merge the 2 examples above but it didn't work;

```
var=key-key
jq ".["${var[i+1]}"]."key""
```

how can I get this work?

Update:

This is the final script, which I've forgot to mention;

```sh
declare -a var=(
    "key-key"
    "key2-key2"
    "key3-key3"
)

for ((i=0; i<${#var[@]})); do
    curl -s "url" | jq ".["${var}"]."something""
done
```

Answer (score 14, accepted):

To have double-quotes in a `jq` command you've enclosed in double-quotes, you'd escape them with a backslash :

```
jq ".[\"key-key\"]"
```

Another problem with your final command is that `${var[i+1]}` expands to the empty string, because this syntax is used to index elements of an array, and you previously defined `var` as a simple string.

A better way to work with variables in `jq` commands is to define them through the `--arg name value` option, after which you can refer to them with `$foo` *in a single-quotes enclosed command* :

```
jq --arg keyName key-key '.[$keyName]'
```

To fix the code included in the update, I would use the following :

```
declare -a var=(
    "key-key"
    "key2-key2"
    "key3-key3"
)

json=$(curl -s "url")

for searchedKey in "${var[@]}"; do
    echo $json | jq --arg keyName $searchedKey '.[$keyName].something'
done
```

Comment: I'm sorry for the confusion, can you please check my update to the question?

Comment: @MarryJane Now you're defining `var` as an array but using it as if it wasn't ; what `jq` command do you actually want to run? I strongly suggest you go by the `--arg` solution I proposed, which your newest edit doesn't invalid

Comment: I just want to get the `key-key` from the curled url with jq. While it works for arrays without dashes in `declare -a var=` part, it doesn't work for arrays with dash in it.

Comment: @MarryJane I really don't see what purpose the array serves there, it looks like `curl -s "url" | jq '.["key-key"].something"` would be just fine. If I'm missing something and it isn't, then I suggest using `curl -s "url" | jq --arg keyName "${var[0]}" '.[$keyName].something'`

Comment: There are actually more stuff in the array list. Sorry I forgot to mention. Can you please check the update again?

Comment: And there is also a loop.

Comment: I'm truly sorry for the confusion. I've accepted your answer now. I forgot about it so that's why I posted my own answer. Sorry about that. And appreciate your help, you saved my day!

Comment: @MarryJane Hey, you ended up doing the right thing so no hard feeling. Sorry I was a bit harsh, I was in the middle of an edit to handle your `for` loop when I saw your own answer and that did bother me at that point. Thanks for accepting my answer, and glad I could help

Comment: My apologies, I just forgot about you mentioned that backslash so that's why I posted my answer and I was in a hurry as well. Sorry my mistake. Cheers!